# select distinct out of three column connectiontable

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, distinct

I have a ef connection table with 3 columns in it. I want to select distinct value out of two of them.

[image]

I want to select distinct rows orderby ResourceId and MetaDataId.
So i want it to return row (1, 3 and 4) in this case.
Ive tried this:

```
  ctx.ResourceMetas.Where(a => a.ResourceId == resourceid).Distinct()});
```

But obviously this gets the distinct values out of all three. Can i somehow choose to get distinct out of just the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may group by your distinct values and then get the max or min of the leftovers.

In your case that you only have one more field you could do it like:

```
ctx.ResourceMetas
   .GroupBy(x=>new{x.ResourceId, x.MetaDataId})
   .Select
   (
       x=>new
       {
           MetaListId = x.Min(m=>m.MetaListId ), 
           ResourceId = x.Key.ResourceId, 
           MetaDataId = x.Key.MetaDataId
       }
   )
   .Where(a => a.ResourceId == resourceid)
```

But in a scenario that you would like the distinct values of 2 fields out of more than three then you would have to do it like:

```
ctx.ResourceMetas
   .GroupBy(x=>new{x.ResourceId, x.MetaDataId})
   .Select
   (
       x=>new
       {
           MetaListId = x.Where(i=>i.MetaListId == x.Min(m=>m.MetaListId)).FirstOrDefault().MetaListId , 
           OtherField = x.Where(i=>i.MetaListId == x.Min(m=>m.MetaListId)).FirstOrDefault().OtherField  , 
           ResourceId = x.Key.ResourceId, 
           MetaDataId = x.Key.MetaDataId
       }
   )
   .Where(a => a.ResourceId == resourceid)
```

Comment: Maybe i should add that i only have the resourceId.